# Windows Store App UI - not responsive

Tags: windows-8

I'm trying to get my head around designing a UI that remains responsive while a long running task is being executed.

To that end, I created a simple app in VS2012 and added the following class to it:

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TaskTest
{
    class Class1
    {
        public async Task<int> Async()
        {
            //simulate a long running process
            for (long x = 0; x < long.MaxValue; x++) { }
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

I then modified the main page's LoadState() method thusly:

```
protected override async void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
{
    await DoLongRunningProcess();
}

private async Task DoLongRunningProcess()
{
    var id = 0;
    id = await new Class1().Async();
    await new MessageDialog(id + "").ShowAsync();
}
```

I want the page to remain responsive while that process executes. However, when I run this code, the page takes a long time to load. What am I doing wrong?

TIA

Answer (score 3):

`async` isn't magic; it just gives you the capability to write asynchronous code. In particular, `async` [does *not* execute code on a background thread](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/04/12/10293335.aspx#5). You can use `Task.Run` to do this.

You may find my [`async`/`await` intro](http://nitoprograms.blogspot.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) or the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

That was helpful. I made the following changes and I got the result I was looking for:

```
class Class1
{
    public int Launch()
    {
        //throw new Exception("Class1 exception");
        for (var i = 0; i < int.MaxValue / 2; i++) ;
        return 1;
    }
}
```

...

```
protected async override void LoadState(Object navigationParameter, Dictionary<String, Object> pageState)
{
    var task = DoLongRunningProcess();
    await task;
    await new MessageDialog(task.Result + "").ShowAsync();
}

private Task<int> DoLongRunningProcess()
{
    return Task.Run<int>(() => new Class1().Launch());
}
```

The page continues to load and after a short pause the message dialog is displayed. Now however, I need to know how to catch exceptions. If I uncomment the //throw new Exception ... line in method Launch(), it is reported as an unhandled exception. I want to catch this exception in the main UI thread (i.e., in the body of method LoadState) but I can't seem to manage it.